# closeness of a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant

Is there some measure that captures the "closeness" of a set of vectors? Say I have a matrix,

$$
A = \left[ \begin{matrix}
0.8 & 0.15 &  0.05 \\
0.82 & 0.09 & 0.09 \\
0.78 & 0.08 & 0.14 \\
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

and another matrix 
$$
B = \left[ \begin{matrix}
0.5 & 0.2 & 0.3 \\ 
0.01 & 0.6 & 0.39 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

Based on this hypothetical measure of "closeness", the row vectors of A are closer to each other than are the rows of B

For any two vectors, I could get their [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

Furthermore, if my matrix was square and had nonzero determinant, the determinant would in some sense capture the "closeness" of the rows, as rows that are very "close", or similar, would span a parallelpiped with smaller volume than would a matrix whose rows were very different

But what if I had a bunch of vectors (say, the rows of a 100 x 3 matrix)?  How would I measure the collective ''closeness'' of the row vectors?  I'm looking for some sort of measure like the determinant, where if the row vectors of a square matrix are close to one another, then the volume of the parallelpiped spanned by these vectors is smaller than if they are quite different - except I could use it for a matrix that is non-square.

Comment: You can take column-wise variance, ending up with 3 numbers.

Comment: There is a vast of measures which can be used to define a "closeness" (or distance) of two sets of vectors and the correct definition strongly depends on the context. If just the volume of the parallelepipeds defined by two sets is *the* correct measure for your application, then of course a determinant formula can be used (taking simply the absolute value of the difference of the volumes as the distance).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your matrix (of row vectors) contains more rows than columns, you can calculate
$\sqrt{\det(A^T A)}$.  In the case that $A$ is a square matrix, this reduces to 
$$
\sqrt{\det(A^T A)} = \sqrt{\det(A^T)\det(A)} = \sqrt{\det(A)^2} =|\det(A)|
$$
Furthermore, we will only have $\sqrt{\det(A^T A)} = 0$ when the columns of $A$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: More material on this approach at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix). In particular, note that $\sqrt{\text{det}(A^T\,A)}$ measures the volume of the parallelotope formed by your vectors.

Answer (score 1):

A standard way to measure how "close" two sets of vectors are is in terms of the *distance* and *principal angles* of subspaces which they span.

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ and $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times q}$ be matrices containing bases of two subspaces $\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, respectively, such that $p=\dim\mathcal{X}\geq\dim\mathcal{Y}=q$ (assuming $q\geq 1$). (In your case, $X=A^T$ and $Y=B^T$). The principal angles $\{\theta_i\}_{i=1}^q$ (where $\theta_i\in[0,\pi/2]$) between $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are defined in a recursive way by
$$
\cos\theta_i=x_i^Ty_i=\max_{\substack{x\in\mathcal{X}\setminus\{0\}\\x\perp x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1}}}\max_{\substack{y\in\mathcal{Y}\setminus\{0\}\\y\perp y_1,\ldots,y_{i-1}}}\frac{x^Ty}{\|x\|_2\|y\|_2},\quad i=1,\ldots,q.
$$

The principal angles can be computed using the SVD. Let $X=Q_XR_X$ and $Y=Q_YR_Y$ be the (thin) QR factorisations of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, that is, the columns of $Q_X$ and $Q_Y$ contain orthonormal bases of $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ in their columns. Now  compute the SVD of $Q_X^TQ_Y$:
$$
Q_X^TQ_Y=U\Sigma V^T,
$$
such that $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices and the singular values in $\Sigma=\mathrm{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_q)$ are ordered in the non-increasing order. It can be shown that the cosines of the principal angles are precisely the singular values $\sigma_i$:
$$
\cos\theta_i = \sigma_i,\quad i=1,\ldots,q.
$$

Note that if $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{Y}$, all singular values of $Q_X^TQ_Y$ are equal to one, that is, the principal angles between $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are zero. On the other hand, if $\mathcal{X}\perp\mathcal{Y}$, then all singular values of $Q_X^TQ_Y$ are equal to zero, that is, the principal angles between $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are equal to $\pi/2$.

If $P_{\mathcal{X}}$ and $P_{\mathcal{Y}}$ are orthogonal projections onto $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$, respectively, then a natural way to define the distance between $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ is
$$
\mathrm{dist}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})=\|P_{\mathcal{X}}-P_{\mathcal{Y}}\|_2.
$$
If $p=q$, this distance can be expressed in terms of principal angles as
$$
\mathrm{dist}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})=\sqrt{1-(\cos\theta_q)^2}.
$$

Comment: After seeing your answer, I realized that my question wasn't as clear as it could be. I'm after the closeness of the rows of a single matrix to eachother, not the closeness of a matrix X to another matrix Y.

Comment: @sinwav Are you looking for something like a measure of linear dependence of vectors?

Comment: Thought I'd revisit this post as I found a solution that was satisfactory. I simply took the average cosine of every pair of two row vectors in the matrix. The normalizing factor was (R choose 2), where R is the number of rows in the matrix.